# Applying an image to a Unity UI Panel

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Does an image have to be a specific type, so that you can simply drag it from a folder in a Unity project and drop it on top of the `Source Image` field of the `Image` component of a `UI` element, such as a `Panel`?

I try to do this with a `jpg` logo, in order to apply it to a `Pane`l element, but it would not apply...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Navigate to the .jpg file within the Unity Editor and select it so that the details appear in the Unity Inspector panel, then change the `Texture Type` to `Sprite (2D and UI)`.  This new Sprite element can now be assigned to the `Source Image` field of the `Image` component.